# Redirecting with base 64 encoded image throwing No reverse Match error

Tags: django, redirect

I have a base 64 image captured in the browser and sent to Django view for processing. I passed the image to the API and depending on the response, I want to redirect to another page with the base 64 image as parameter but it's generating an error. here is the codes.

@login_required
def snap_rider(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
``` base64 image``your text ```
image = request.POST['photo_data']

```
    #Calculate the size of the image in bytes
    image_size = len(image) * 3 / 4
    if image_size > 5 * 1024 * 1024:
        return render(request, 'rider_management/snap-rider.html', {'error_message': 'Image size is too large. Please select a smaller image.'})
    
    search_request_data = {
        "images": [image],
        "min_score": 0.7,
        "search_mode": "FAST"  
    }
    
     
    response = requests.post(SEARCH_URL, json=search_request_data, headers=headers)
    if response.status_code == 200:
        data = response.json()
        if data == []:
              return redirect('create_rider', image=image)
       
    else:
        print(f"Error: {response.status_code} - {response.text}")
 
return render(request, 'rider_management/snap-rider.html')
```

The view I'm redirecting to:
@login_required
def create_rider(request):
image = request.POST.get('image')

the urls.py

```
path('create-rider/', views.create_rider, name='create_rider'),
```

Comment: please provide error log

Comment: NoReverseMatch at /snap-rider/
Reverse for 'create_rider' with keyword arguments '{'image': 'iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAUAAAADwCAYAAABxLb1rAAAAA..........Not Found.